# How to retrieve Hive table Partition Location?

Tags: hive

Show Partitions  --> In Hive/Spark, this command only provides the Partition, without providing the location information on hdfs/s3

Since we maintain different location for each partition in a table, is there a way to retrieve the location information along using Hive/Spark without querying the Metastore tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DESCRIBE FORMATTED <db>.table` will return will give you the location, among a lot of other data.  There will be a line in the output that starts with `LOCATION`.

Comment: Thx @Andrew for my scenario needed - describe formatted db.table_name (partition_name=partition_value)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the query: 
show table extended like 'your_table_name' partition (partition_name);

This provides a more concise information and also in a format that is easy to pass if you want to extract information using a shell script.

Comment: It worked with slight change - show table extended like 'your_table_name' partition (partition_name=partition_value);